# symfony doctrine:generate:entities cannot auto-load annotations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I run Symfony 3.1.5, PHP 7.0.12 and composer 1.2.1.

I have a simple entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Event
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM|Entity
 * @ORM|Table(name="event")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM|Id
     * @ORM|GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="guid")
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="datetimetz")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="datetimetz")
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @ORM|Column(type="text")
     */
    private $location;
}
```

[The documentation states](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) that I can run

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Event
```

in order to create getters and setters for my private attributes. I run into the following error there:

```
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping" in class AppBundle\Entit
  y\Event does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

As the annotation exists as alias `@ORM` I guessed it is an autoloading problem.

I googled around and found some [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937261/autloading-not-working-correct-using-autoloader-php-in-vendor-directory) which linked to [this plugin](https://github.com/indigophp/doctrine-annotation-autoload), which also does not work.

All posts seem to be related to the fact that the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` class is not autoloaded in the conventional way, but needs to be loaded separately. But I cannot find a definite guide on how to get this up and running for the console. Could you please help?

Comment: replace the `|` with the `\ ` as example `@ORM\Entity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your annotations with the following :

```
/**
 * EntityName
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="table_name")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PATH TO REPO")
 */
```

use \ instead of |

Comment: Looks like I need a new pair of glasses. In the docs, I read it as pipe. Thanks