# How to autoload custom annotation classes without using AnnotationRegistry?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, composer-php, autoload

I'm using Doctrine Annotations library (not the whole Doctrine, only annotations) and want to make a custom annotation class.

composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.6"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "annotations\\": "annotations",
      "entities\\": "entities"
    }
  }
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

$annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(entities\MyClass::class);
$classAnnotations = $annotationReader->getClassAnnotations($reflectionClass);
var_dump($classAnnotations);
```

entities/MyClass.php

```
<?php

namespace entities;

use annotations\TestAnnotation;

/**
 * @TestAnnotation("123")
 */
class MyClass
{

}
```

annotations/TestAnnotation.php

```
<?php

namespace annotations;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("CLASS")
 */
final class TestAnnotation
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $value;
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@annotations\TestAnnotation" in class entities\MyClass does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

The only solution i found on the Internet is to use AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader or something similar, but it is deprecated so i'd like to solve the problem in another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to work around registering a loader is explicit `require_once` of all files with custom annotations somewhere during application's bootstrap (such approach was used in the MongoDB ODM but was dropped).

In the next major version `annotations` will rely on autoloading so no code will be required for the setup. To have a future-proof code you could use:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

if (class_exists(AnnotationRegistry::class)) {
    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
}
```

You could explicitly pass Composer's autoloader but `class_exists` will work just fine given Composer's autoloader is already in use.

Comment: Is it right that autoloading without Registry will only be available since v2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question and answered it myself as apparently the answer to it turned out to be far more obscure than I could have imagined, ultimately taking a whole day to track down, though easy enough to fix:

```
composer require “yogarine/doctrine-annotation-autoload”
```

```
composer dump-autoload
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59966965/4538469 for details.